# Installing SQL Server on Centos 7.3

Tags: sql-server, linux, centos7

I'm having some trouble installing SQL server in a fresh centos 7.3 in a virtual server in Soyoustart.

After installing sql server using yum sollowing microsoft tutorial I run the the setup command and I got the following error:

```
-bash-4.2$ sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388
and found in /usr/share/doc/mssql-server/LICENSE.TXT.

Do you accept the license terms? [Yes/No]:Yes
Setting up Microsoft SQL Server
Enter the new SQL Server system administrator password: 
Confirm the new SQL Server system administrator password: 
sqlservr: File.cpp:972: virtual SystemStatus File::Map(void *, ssize_t, int, int, off_t, void *&, ssize_t &): Assertion `mappedBase == address' failed.
ls: no se puede acceder a /proc/2384/smaps: No existe el fichero o el directorio
cat: /proc/2384/sched: No existe el fichero o el directorio
find: ‘/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d’: Permiso denegado
find: ‘/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/auditd’: Permiso denegado
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operación no permitida
No journal files were found.
No journal files were found.
tail: no se puede abrir «/var/log/messages» para lectura: Permiso denegado
ls: no se puede acceder a /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog*: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a /var/opt/mssql/log/exception.log: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a /var/opt/mssql/log/SQLDu*.txt: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a /var/opt/mssql/log/SQLDu*.mdmp: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a /var/opt/mssql/log/system_health*: No existe el fichero o el directorio
Failed to change system administrator password with error code 1. 
Please check the setup log in /var/opt/mssql/log/setup-20170419-091114.log
for more information.
nohup: se redirige la salida de error a la salida estándar
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What file system are you using? I've seen this error when the file system was not one of the ones we support for SQL Server: XFS or EXT4. See more details about supported configurations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup.

Comment: We use ext4 lv or ext4 primary